# CDH4 multi node cluster installation

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup a CDH4 multi node cluster.

Datanode is down and I get the following FATAL error:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: please add more clarification, what have you tried so far and what you got

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update your configuration files and logs.